# Jinja2/Flask url_for with 4 parameters creates a GET request

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have the following code in my template:

```
{% block body %}
  {% for x in range(0, 4) %}
    <a href="{{url_for('quiz', category=category, id=id2,  type=clean_types[x]|string) }}">
    {{clean_answers[x]}}
    </a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

However, for my last parameter, instead of getting:

```
127.0.0.1:5000/quiz/Books/1/True
```

I get this:

```
127.0.0.1:5000/quiz/Books/1?type=True
```

Can you explain why this happens, and how I fix it?

I tried with and without the |string conversion, I tried setting a separate variable to `clean_types[x]` first, and then converting it, but it still appears as ?type=True.

for reference, `clean_types` is a list with 4 items, either True or False in various orders and it gets passed with the return of the template in flask.

the route that generates the links is:

```
@app.route('/quiz/<category>/<int:id>')

def quiz(category, id):

    questions = list(db_quiz.getQuestionsByCategory(category))

    clean_question = questions[id][1]
    print(id)
    print(id+1)
    print(clean_question)

    dirty_answers = []

    for x in range(0, 4):
        dirty_answers.append(questions[0][2 + x])

    shuffled_answers = random.sample(dirty_answers, len(dirty_answers))

    clean_answers = [i.split(',')[0] for i in shuffled_answers]
    clean_types = [i.split(',')[1] for i in shuffled_answers]

    print("---------------")

    print(clean_answers)
    print(clean_types)

    clean_types_v2 = ('ja', 'nee', 'nee', 'nee')

    id2=id+1
    return flask.render_template('quiz.html',
                                 category=category,
                                 id2=id2,
                                 clean_question=clean_question,
                                 clean_types=clean_types,
                                 clean_answers=clean_answers)
```

base template

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>tinyQuiz</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/favicon.png') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/reset.css') }}" />
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" />
{% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
<div class="verticalAlign">
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png') }}" />

    <h1>tinyQuiz{% block h1 %}{% endblock %}</h1><br/>
    <h2>{% block h2 %}{% endblock %}</h2><br id="br" />
    <h3>{% block h3 %}{% endblock %}</h3><br/><br id="br"/>

    {% block body %} {% endblock %}
</div>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.2.1.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

quiz template that extends it:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head %}
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/quiz.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block h2 %} You are playing: {{ category.capitalize() }} {% endblock %}

{% block h3 %} {{ clean_question }} {% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{% for x in range(0, 4) %}
    <a  href="{{url_for('quiz', category=category, id=id2, type=clean_types[x]) }}">
        {{clean_answers[x]}}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

the route the link should point to is:

```
@app.route('/quiz/<category>/<int:id>/<type>')
def trivia(category, id, type):
    if type == 'True':
        # scores.append(1) #add one to show you got a question correctly
        return flask.render_template('trivia_true.html')
    else:
        # scores.append(0) #add zero to show you failed to answer correctly
        return flask.render_template('trivia_false.html')
```

here is a link to the project on [github](https://github.com/elfensky/tinyQuiz/tree/master)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. My. God.

I was stupid and completely misunderstood the url_for documentation.

the 'something' at the start of the url_for refers to the function/path in flask, and is NOT, unlike what I thought, just a string for the url.

changing my link to

```
        <a  href="{{ url_for('trivia', category=category, id=id2, type=clean_types[x]) }}">
```

fixed my problem.

It's now of course also obvious why it generated a GET request instead of a normal link - it was referring it "itself", so a new parameter on the same path would be a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

I see your HTML a href link is correct. But in your `quiz` function route url construction is wrong, It should be...

```
@app.route('/quiz/<category>/<int:id>/<type>')
def quiz(category, id, type):
```

Comment: I have it that in the route it redirects, but the issue is that the link the previous route creates isn't correct.

Comment: @app.route('/') creates links that redirets to @app.route('/quiz/<category>/<int:id>'), and that page in turn should generate links that would redirect to @app.route('/quiz/<category>/<int:id>/<type>'). The route that creates the <type> doesn't have nor need it as a parameter, and when I add it it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Please include the relevant minimal code here... I will start to look

Comment: I've added the base.html template and the quiz.html template that extends it. Thank you.

Comment: Can you paste your index.html ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146983/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-elfensky).